# Добавить уже готовый js таймер в React компонент

Tags: reactjs

Начал миграцию с HTML/JS на React, я в этом деле новичок. Может кто знает как добавить функию таймера в реакт компонент?

```
export default class  HeaderMain extends React.Component {

render() {
    const {module, themNum, themTitle, time} = this.props;
    return (
        <div id="m-title" className="m-header">
            <div className="m-header__caption caption">
                <h2 className="caption__title">{module}</h2>
                <h3 className="caption__theme">ТЕМА {themNum}</h3>
            </div>
            <h2 className="m-header__title" id="theory-name">
                [ {themTitle} _] 
            </h2>
            <div id="m-timers">
                <div className="m-timer">
                    <div className="m-timer__time">
                        <span id="m-timer">{time}</span>
                        <p>на прочтение</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className=" m-timer__img " id="m-timer__img"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

function (document){

```
const time = document.getElementById('m-timer');

let hour = 0;
let second = 0;
let minute = 26;
let timerInterval;

function timer(time){

    let end = false;

    if ( second > 0 ) second--;
    else {
        second = 60;

        if ( minute > 0 ) {
            minute--;
            time.innerHTML = `${minute} мин`;
        } else {
            second = 60;

            if ( hour > 0 ) hour--;
            else end = true;
        }
    }
    if (end) {
        clearInterval(timerInterval)
        //alert("Время вышло!");
    }
}

function timerStart() {
    const time = document.getElementById('m-timer');
    timerInterval = setInterval( () => timer(time), 1000);
}

function timerStop() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function init(){
    (!document.hidden) ? timerStart()
        : timerStop()
}

const hwTheoryRender = document.querySelector(".wrapper_theory");
    if (hwTheoryRender) {
        hwTheoryRender.addEventListener('click', () => {
            setTimeout(init, 1000)
            })
    };
```

}(document);

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить метод `componentDidMount()`:

```
export default class  HeaderMain extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // здесь вызов таймера
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.doSomething();
    }, 1000);
  }

  // здесь его остановка
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  render() {}
    ...
  }
}
```

Кроме того, вам нужно избавиться от прямых манипуляций с DOM и делать это через пропсы/состояние. Подробнее обо всём этом можно узнать [здесь](https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/react-course-ru/content/) или [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/react) для начала, оба на русском языке.